# Shiny: problems with actionButton (no trespassing signal even

Tags: r, shiny, dashboard, shinydashboard

I'm building a Shiny app and for the last two days I'm being blocked on the following step: I've put a "Submit" button on a typeform and apparently there are no problems, but everytime I run the app I can't click on it because for the very beginning it shows me a "no trespassing" signal disallowing me to do nothing else.

Here's the code I'm using:

```
    # Packages ----
if(require("pacman")=="FALSE"){
  install.packages("pacman")
}
library(pacman)
pacman::p_load(dplyr, tidyr, shiny, shinydashboard)



# Global scope ----

dish <- c("Salad", "Spaghetti Carbonara", "Scrambled eggs")
allergens <- c("sesame", "lactose", "eggs")
keywords <- c("veggie", "pasta", "none")
dishes <- data.frame(dish, allergens, keywords)


# Function to label mandatory fields ----
labelMandatory <- function(label) {
  tagList(
    label,
    span("*", class = "mandatory_star")
  )
}

appCSS <- ".mandatory_star { color: red; }" #to make the asterisk red

MandatoryFields_dishes <- c(names(dishes[,-3]))
fields_dishes <- c(names(dishes))



ui <- dashboardPage(
                    dashboardHeader(title = "sample"),
                    dashboardSidebar(
                      sidebarMenu(
                        menuItem("Dishes", tabName = "dishes")
                      )
                    ),

                    dashboardBody(

                      # Dishes
                      tabItems(
                        tabItem(tabName = "dishes",
                                tabsetPanel(
                                  tabPanel("Typeform",
                                           fluidPage(
                                             shinyjs::useShinyjs(),
                                             shinyjs::inlineCSS(appCSS),
                                             titlePanel("Dish introduction"),
                                             div(
                                               id="form",
                                               textInput("dish", labelMandatory("Dishes"), ""),
                                               textInput("allergens", label = "Allergens",""),
                                               textInput("keyword", label = "Keyword", ""),
                                               actionButton("submit", "Submit", class="btn-primary")
                                             )
                                           ))
                                ))

                      ))
)



server <- function(input, output) {



  observe({
    mandatoryFilled_dishes <-
      vapply(MandatoryFields_dishes,
             function(x) {
               !is.null(input[[x]]) && input[[x]] != ""
             },
             logical(1))
    mandatoryFilled_dishes <- all(mandatoryFilled_dishes)

    shinyjs::toggleState(id = "submit", condition = mandatoryFilled_dishes)
  })


}


shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I guess I'm missing something on the server. If someone could help me I'll be very grateful, lots of thanks in advance.

Comment: it looks to me that all is fine, you have 2 mandatory fields in `MandatoryFields_dishes` which are the `dish` and `allergens`, then it will need them to be active in order to push the button, all works as it should. I dont understand your question

Comment: The problem I'm having is that once I run the application, when I put the pointer on the button it becomes a no-trespassing signal, even if the mandatory fields are filled.